# Configurar PHP y MySQL - Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

```
Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available.
```

En el momento de cargar el `php.ini` no me visualiza que esté cargando la extensión

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

En el `pnp.ini` he habilitado las extensiones, he copiado los DLL en System32, he hecho de todo pero aún no me carga, no logro que PHP se configure con MySQL.

Comment: tienes definido mysql.default_host = en tu .ini?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la pronta respuesta. Si, en el .ini está tal cual te lo copio aquí:

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-host
mysql.default_host =

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para agregar esto, no logro distinguir el `.ini` desde acá.

Comment: lo más probable es que habilitaste mysql, pero luego no reiniciaste apache

Answer (score 1):

Trate de ubicar y establecer el siguiente parámetro en su php.ini (que se encuentra en la sección de extensiones dinámicas):

```
extension = php_mysql.dll
```

Antes de este cambio, podría hacer un simple script php sin ejecutar MySQL, como este :
"

```
<? Php 
phpinfo ((); 
?>
```

"
para saber si tiene mysql instalado

sino

descargue http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libmysql

adicione `libmysql.dll` to `C:\windows\system32`

reinicie apache

Comment: Por lo que comenta Ozcar, esto ya lo realizó :(